# Date picker is dynamic in SSDT but not in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs, ssdt, visual-studio-2010

Running SQL Server 2012 SP1 and SSDT from same distribution. (VS2010) 
When I display a report in SSDT the date selector on a date parameter is dynamic or responsive. When you click on the date (month/year)  the date picker can zoom in/out. Or drill in/out (Apologies if I'm using the wrong terminology).

However looking at same report in SSRS, the date picker doesn't have the same functionality.  You can click left and right arrows to get last/next month but clicking on the date does nothing.

Does this only work in SSDT? or should it also work in SSRS?

If it should work in SSRS, any suggestion of where to start looking would be greatly appreciated. Is it report setting? an SSRS setting? a browser setting?

If there is a better description of this feature please let me know and I'll update my question.

Thanks

Peter